# Nested doughnut plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame showing the number of patents by category by country.

I want to create a nested doughnut plot showing the proportion of patents per category on the inner plot and then the breakdown of patent classes by country on the outer plot. Alternatively, I want to show the proportion of countries patenting on the inner plot and then the breakdown of patent classes on the outer plot.

I tried `webr`, and it does this, but I have little control over formatting. I prefer to do this in `ggplot` but I am getting my knickers in a serious knot.

I am trying to implement this solution https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-create-a-ggplot2-pie-and-donut-chart-on-same-plot/42798, but I am getting confused by how to split patent class labels.

I have 3073 patents, grouped into 8 patent classes for 119 countries.

My data can be accessed here: https://github.com/aterhorst/data/blob/master/patents.Rdata

```
class_breakdown <- lens_reformatted %>%
  select(class = value, country_code = `Country Code`, country = `Country Name`) %>%
  mutate(country_code = ifelse(is.na(country), "XX", country_code),
         country = ifelse(country_code == "XX", "Unknown", country)) %>%
  group_by(class, country) %>%
  summarise(patents = sum(n())) 

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = class_breakdown %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise(tot = sum(patents)), aes(x = 2, y = tot, fill = class)) +
  geom_col(data = class_breakdown, aes(x = 3, y = patents, fill = class), color = "black", lwd = 0.15) +
  scale_fill_aaas() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

I need to figure out how to arrange the country breakdown and do the labeling. Any help would be appreciated!